# JavaScript presionar tecla Dead dos veces, pasa validación de input que permita ingresar solo numeros

Tags: javascript, keyboard, onkeypress

tengo la siguiente función que valida que solo se pueda ingresar caracteres numericos en un input text, el problema es que si presiono dos veces la tecla Dead ésta se ingresa ´ en el input text.

```
input_numerico.onkeydown = tecladoNumerico;
function tecladoNumerico(e) {
  if (e.key != 0 && e.key != 1 && e.key != 2 && e.key != 3 && e.key != 4 && e.key != 5 && e.key != 6 && e.key != 7 && e.key != 8 && e.key != 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucionar mi problema.

Answer (score -1):

Una manera de evitar cuando la tecla *Dead* es presionada es usar el evento [onkeypress](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) para verificar si la tecla presionada es la tecla `Dead` y así evitar el comportamiento por defecto.

```
function preventDead(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Dead') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

**(** *Lo que puede ocurrir de manera inesperada es que puede haber navegadores que pueden manejar la tecla "Dead" de manera diferente.* **)**

```js
function isNumber(event) {
  var key = event.key;
  return key >= 48 && key <= 57;  
}

function preventDead(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Dead') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

//onkeypress o keydown
document.getElementById('n').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (!isNumber(event)) {
    preventDead(event);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="n">
```

Solo una observación; Las teclas `e` y `E` son interpretadas como valores **numéricos** ya que pueden representar números en notación **científica**.

> ADVERTENCIA:

La tecla `Dead` no es compatible con los navegadores, esto se debe a que esta tecla no es común en la mayoría de los teclados.
Y la forma en que los navegadores la manejan es diferente cuando se trata de esta tecla `Dead`.

*La* **Dead** *es una tecla especial que genera diacríticos, que son acentos que no se utilizan en muchos idiomas humanos.
Un diacrítico es un carácter que se presionó previamente.*

Una abordaje diferente es usar una expresión regular y verificar si es un número.

```
function isNumber(event) {
  let key = event.key;
  return /[0-9]/.test(key);
}
```

Comment: ¿En qué navegador lo probaste? Lo probé en Firefox 117 y aparece `´´` (lo que OP quiere evitar).

Comment: Dejé advertido que no todos los navegadores lo **soportan!!!!!!!**

Comment: Lo sé, lo leí. Eso no quita mi pregunta :)